# How to add custom css and js to angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli

In angular 2, I could just add them in the **index.html** like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycss.css">
```

But in angular 4 it has to be added to the **angular-cli.json** file in the styles and script array section.

In my situation they don't seem to be loaded at all. No error but when I view the app in the browser, I know the styles didn't load. 
When I add the styles and js to the index.html file too it doesn't get loaded, I get a 404 in the console.

How do I fix this? Below is my version of Angular cli:
@angular/cli : 1.0.2
Node : 6.9.2

Comment: Have you restart your server once you've added the css files to the `styles` array? Try to break your server and re-run `ng serve`

Comment: What have you configured inside angular-cli.json?

Comment: you still can put them as link tags. Angular-cli creates a `assets` folder, put them in and reference them in your index.html file (under `src="assets/yourPath.css"`)

Answer (score 14):

If you are using angular cli then go to your **.angular-cli.json** and then you can get **"styles":[ ] as well "scripts":[ ]**
inside these you can add your css files and js files

```
 "styles": [
            yourfirst-css-file , //comma (,)is important
            your-second-css-file
          ],
```

Eg:-

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],

"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ],
```

and 404 error means that the file is not found.Try and append the complete "url"  folder(src).